Does using mainnet-beta rpc have limitations for frontend?
I've tested all the free plans of QuickNode, Alchemy, Helius, and Syndica. They are very slow, and the probability of transaction failure is very high. I don't know if the premium plans offer any advantages or if the same conditions will be repeated. Mainnet-beta has better quality, but its documentation states that:

Maximum number of requests per 10 seconds per IP: 100
Maximum number of requests per 10 seconds per IP for a single RPC: 40
Maximum concurrent connections per IP: 40
Maximum connection rate per 10 seconds per IP: 40
Maximum amount of data per 30 second: 100 MB

I want to use mainnet-beta only for the frontend using react-wallet-adapter. In this scenario, the user sends the transaction from the frontend and there is no backend for confirmation, just client-side
When a transaction is made from the client side, is the IP of that person sent to the RPC or my server's IP? For example, if 100 users simultaneously make transactions from my site, will the access be limited, or is it defined separately for each user?

It depends on how the app is designed.
Usually, if you're using wallet adapter, then the wallet will actually do the work of sending the transaction, and typically wallets use their own RPC nodes rather than the public ones. In that case, the rate limiting is set by the wallet nodes.
If you don't have a backend, then users will make requests from their browser straight to the public RPC node, so the rate limiting will be based on their IP, and not a server's.
